# Automation of selecting future and past date from datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, protractor

I am working on e2e using protractor. There is a scenario where I need to select one future date(10 days ahead from today), one past date(5days previous from today). If today's date is 12/20/2017 I need to select 12/30/2017 (future date) and 12/15/2017(past date) from two separate datepickers. I tried the below code, but everytime today's date is getting selected even though future date is specified by adding the number of days(10). Future date is correctly printed on console, but it is selecting today's date from the datepicker. Please let me how to do this.

```
function consentEffectiveDate(){

        var picker = element(by.model('case.consentEffectiveDate'));
        // get today's date
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate()+10;
        console.log("date: "+dd);
        var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

        if (dd < 10) {
            dd = '0' + dd
        }

        if (mm < 10) {
            mm = '0' + mm
        }
        today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
        picker.sendKeys(today);
        console.log("date:"+today);
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

html code

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly"
    class="form-control effectiveDate ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-pattern ng-touched" 
    name="effectiveDate" id="effectiveDate"
    ng-model="case.consentEffectiveDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
    ng-pattern="/^([0]?\d{1}|[1][0-2])\/(([0-2]?\d{1})|([3][0,1]{1}))\/(([1]{1}[9]{1}[9]{1}\d{1})|([1-9]{1}\d{3}))$/" 
    data-ng-change="model.compareDates(case.consentEffectiveDate, case.consentExpiresDate, new_consent);"
    ng-class="{ 'has-error' : new_consent.effectiveDate.$invalid &amp;&amp; (new_consent.effectiveDate.$dirty || submitted)}"
    style="">
```

Comment: Can you kindly update your question with the HTML code for the Date Picker?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue before. For me it was that the date-picker wasn't focused by protractor and therefore the date wasn't sent to the input field.

Try focusing the element by clicking it first and then pass the keys.

```
var picker = element(by.model('case.consentEffectiveDate'));
picker.click().sendKeys(today);
```

If there is a possibility that the date is pre-filled, you could write it like this to remove the previous date from the picker before entering the new date.

```
picker.click().sendKeys(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "a", protractor.Key.NULL, today);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried with both the possibilities, focusing and pre-filled date but didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you help me with usage of evaluate(picker.evaluate() ), how to use and protractor docs for this?

Comment: Hm, okay. Could you update your question with the html code for the date picker as well @HemaLatha ? It would help with identifying the problem.

Comment: html code  `<input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="form-control effectiveDate ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-pattern ng-touched" name="effectiveDate" id="effectiveDate" ng-model="case.consentEffectiveDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" ng-pattern="/^([0]?\d{1}|[1][0-2])\/(([0-2]?\d{1})|([3][0,1]{1}))\/(([1]{1}[9]{1}[9]{1}\d{1})|([1-9]{1}\d{3}))$/" data-ng-change="model.compareDates(case.consentEffectiveDate, case.consentExpiresDate, new_consent);" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : new_consent.effectiveDate.$invalid &amp;&amp;  (new_consent.effectiveDate.$dirty ||  submitted)}" style="">`